# What could be causing ZVS imbalance?

Tags: flyback, induction, zvs

I am using a ZVS driver to test some properties of induction and power transfer. I have never PREVIOUSLY had a problem with MOSFET heating in my designs.

Today I changed one coil for another larger one to test more power.  I modified the capacitance and inductance as necessary to achieve a similar frequency (which I will fine tune later). This is just a copper coil with .33uF on the first and 2uF on the second.

I am getting some strange behavior on the scope and heating of the MOSFETs using the larger coil.

Following are some oscilloscope pictures: 1 & 2 are probing each side of the coil, the math line (purple) is 1-2.  The problem with the second coil is that even though it is producing a nice aggregate sine wave each side of the coil is getting noisier.

What I get normally:
[image: What I get normally]

What I get using the larger coil:
[image: Issue with larger coil...]

Comment: Check your MOSFET voltage on the primary side.  It looks like you are ringing and I bet you have a switching spike that exceeds your VDS max.  When a spike like this occurs, the MOSFET acts like a zener and clips the spike at its breakdown voltage.  This is what often causes the heating.

Comment: what are those curves representing?

Comment: 1 & 2 are probing each side of the coil,
the math line (purple) is 1-2

Comment: Hi John, I assume you mean for the gate? The gate is at 11.812v - well within spec, powered from a separate supply. Sorry if I am misunderstanding you

Comment: Unless you mean primary for a tesla. I am not using my tesla currently, this is the voltage on the fet / there is only a primary coil

Comment: Sorry if I am misunderstanding.  I am meaning the FET drains.

Comment: The drains are not being pushed anywhere near - the voltages quoted are on the drain. Hence why I'm on here, strange behaviour for sure

Comment: Does the scope have a good ground? Since the math trace is ok...I'm lead to think the issue is noise on the scope.

Comment: Nice Sine CLC filter as it should look with 180 deg phase shift wrt V.  , where are your design specs? as in what your expected IN/OUT

Comment: No schematic, No block diagram? no specs? no answer. For more power you need a smaller L, *not bigger L* with impedance matching from source to load.

Comment: I still suspect the oscillation - looks like around 1 Mhz.  If your coil has capacitance in the windings, this can happen.  What does your gate voltage look like?  See if it you are getting oscillations near the gate threshold voltage.

Comment: Hi Tony,

I did not mean to miss out the schematic, it doesn't matter if I use my own design ZVS, or a Mazilli/Royer which I have also now tried (but the mazilli blows up) - http://gaugeboson.com/electronics/Mazilli1.jpg

I often test loads to find the resonant frequency of the tank for high power loads by throwing a mazilli on it and seeing what happens, but the gates go into parasitic oscillations and blow within 60 seconds - neither mosfet latches on immediately, only when overheated.

Comment: Hi MadHatter - the oscillations are real, I have a battery powered pocket scope that I cannot get images from and it shows the oscillations in the sine wave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone that commented.

Your comments were taken on board and I have since looked into this more fully. I built my own circuit to drive this load and that is what the scopes are from. The coil was 7 turns of 5mm copper, with 2uH capacitance added. My driver did not blow up but because I was having issues and have quite complex schematics I reverted to sticking a mazilli driver on it to see what would happen and determine if it was my circuit or the load ([Mazilli driver](http://gaugeboson.com/electronics/hv/Mazilli1.jpg) from - http://gaugeboson.com/electronics/high_voltage.html)

When the Mazilli driver was connected it would heat rapidly and blow in about a minute @ 150-200w. The parasitics pictured were greater in amplitude than the sine in the case of the mazilli.

Anyway I have found the answer after about 18 hours of troubleshooting, 5 mosfets and 2 burnt caps later, and post it as it may help some people using Mazilli drivers for their tesla coils/ etc as I have done in the past

**Stray inductance.**

If your having a similar issue with your flyback drivers as I was having with my own circuit, and then the mazilli, it may help to place larger capacitance directly across (i.e. as close as possible) to the drains of the fets. This stopped the Mazilli blowing up and allowed me to then attach and troubleshoot my circuit (well the load, as the circuit operates fine on other loads). From testing I would say that the capacitance at this location should be at least 1/3rd of the total capacitance of the tank to eliminate the issue, at least in my case.

I can only fathom that the inductance between the load and the fets was setting up another resonant tank that resonated upon switching the fets due to Miller effect. In the case of the mazilli, which relies upon the gates being pulled low by the fet that's on, it would resonate all over the place in and out of the linear region, thus destruction. On the mazilli I got as much as 8mhz oscillations occurring. I am not sure if coupling of the coil to the circuit could cause such interference or not?

Anyway, thank you for the input of others and hope that inadvertently this question may assist someone experiencing parasitics in their own ZVS. I still don't know why this load was so troublesome as the leads are very short but will re-design it more appropriately moving forward.